# PLSQL pipelined function to return a list

Tags: oracle, function, plsql, pipelined-function

I'm trying to create a function to get a list of values from my database. After some researches I found that I need to use the PIPELINE function and I found some examples. I did my function but I somehow got 2 errors that I don't understand.

Here's my code :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE LISTE_VALUES AS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(2000);
/    

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION F_GET_VAL(
        PI_1 IN VARCHAR2,
        PI_2 IN NUMBER,
        PI_3 IN VARCHAR2)
    RETURN LISTE_VALUES PIPELINED

    IS
        W_ROW_COUNT NUMBER := 0;

    BEGIN

        FOR CUR IN (SELECT VALUE FROM TABLE 
                    WHERE ...
                      ...

                    )

        LOOP
            PIPE ROW (CUR);
            W_ROUNT_COUNT := W_ROW_COUNT + 1;
        END LOOP;

        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('There were '
                            || W_ROW_COUNT
                            || ' rows selected' );

    END F_GET_VAL;
    /
```

And These are the errors I get :

> [Error] PLS-00382 : PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type   (at the
>   line : PIPE ROW (CUR);)
>
> [Error] PLS-00201 : PLS-00201: identifier 'W_ROUNT_COUNT' must be
>   declared
>
> (at the line : W_ROUNT_COUNT := W_ROW_COUNT + 1;)

For the first error I triple checked and `VALUE` in my table has a type `VARCHAR2(2000)`, exactly as I declared my type at the beginning (a table of `VARCHAR2(2000)`).

And for the second, I don't understand because I declared the variable `W_ROW_COUNT` in my IS statement.

If someone could help me it would be nice !
Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A `PIPE ROW` can be created for a single row and not the cursor's name variable, which contains the entire recordset.

Just use

**`PIPE ROW ( cur.value );`**

instead of `PIPE ROW ( cur );`

You may also store the query output into a collection and then pipe each element.

Regarding the error due to `W_ROW_COUNT`, it is a typo. You have wrongly used it as `W_ROUNT_COUNT` while adding it.

[**Demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=a027abe2a37dec9576419255bf1f3c99)

Comment: Thank you very much for your clear answer, it now totally works :)
My bad for the second error ... didn't see that !

Comment: Note that `cur` here is a record variable, *not* a cursor.

Comment: @JeffreyKemp : Thanks, I hope now I have worded it appropriately.